# Can I implement paint style effects with jsPlumb 1.3.3?

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am trying to implement the example given [here](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/chart/jquery.html). I have copied the [code from the demo](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/chart/demo.js). In the demo, the color and style of widgets changes on hover.

But I'm not able to achieve this. The only difference is that I am using jsPlumb-1.3.3 and they are using 1.5.5. Does that matter? And if so, where can I download jsPlumb-1.5.5 from?

Comment: make sure that you used the required java-script libraries.

Comment: https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/archive/master.zip
download github file.. you can find code into:
Demo>chart>JQuery.html
open it with browser it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo you are trying to implement has changed quite a bit since jsPlumb 1.3.3. If you want the version from 1.3.3, you can see the old code in the repo:

- https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/blob/04013d793cae682ca7b361b5550fb8583b028bfe/demo/jquery/chartDemo.html
- https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/blob/04013d793cae682ca7b361b5550fb8583b028bfe/demo/js/1.3.3/chartDemo.js

Implementing that demo with 1.3.3 should work.

If you want to upgrade to 1.5.5, you can pick one of the jQuery-compatible distributions from [the jsPlumb dist/js folder.](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/tree/master/dist/js)